# The matlab FMINCON solution terminating at upper bound

Tags: matlab, optimization, curve-fitting, nonlinear-optimization

I am running an optimisation algorithm using FMINCON SQP to optimise a problem of 8 variables. Following are the parameters:

```
g = [g1 g2 g3 g4 g5 g6 g7 g8] %my variables
lb = [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0];
ub = [1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1];
```

The minimisation of Objective function is defined as:

```
sse = sum((test results - calculated)).^2;
```

subject to linear constraints:

```
A = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1];
b = 1;
ceq = [];
```

The aim of the optimisation process is to fit a curve as shown in the fig. [image: curve fitting]
The blue line represents test results and the magenta is the curve obtained from the optimised variables.

**Problem**: Although I am able to fit the curve as required, the optimised variables end up with values in the upper bound. I have implemented the following code for `fmincon`:

```
options = optimset('Display', 'iter','Algorithm','sqp', 'TolX',1e-10, 'TolFun', 1e-20,'MaxIter', 10000000000,'MaxFunEvals', 10000000000);

[y,fval,exitflag,output] = fmincon('objective', ginit, A,b,[],[],lb,ub,[], options);
```

Could anybody please advice me about a robust method to overcome this issue of optimisation solution terminating at the upper bound? Could you please also let me know what might be the reason behind this issue?

Comment: why is it bad to be at the upper bound? This usually suggests that your search space is too narrow (i.e. your upper bound is too low). You will most likely end-up with a trade-off of errors... this does not necessarily be an accurate fit to a section of your curve (as your image suggests). This depends on how you formulate the objective-function

Answer (score 0):

Beside the very accurate comment from max, are you positive that you mean this:

sse = sum((test results - calculated).^2);

Instead of this:

sse = sum((test results - calculated)).^2;

?